# Library to generate Version 1 UUIDs to be called from Java

Tags: open-source, library, java

[Version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) UUIDs represent a point in space *and* in time.

The "space" part is the [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) taken from the networking port of the computer to uniquely identify where the id was generated (nearly unique, there have been some infamous screw-ups in assigning MAC addresses by the networking hardware manufacturers).

The "time" part is a 60-bit timestamp, being the number of 100-[nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) intervals since [midnight 15 October 1582](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Adoption) [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

## Java omits Version 1

No implementation of Version 1 UUID is required by the Java specifications.

Presumably this is because of the security and privacy concerns from potentially divulging your MAC address and the moment of creation.

I am looking for a 3rd-party implementation of a Version 1 UUID generator.

- Pure Java implementation, would be preferred. But a native implementation would work as well if wrapped in a Java library, and working on macOS, MS Windows, BSD, and Linux at least. Most every host OS provides a robust UUID implementation.
- Open-source is required, so its source code can be verified.
- A fee is acceptable.